CORS/(Unauthorized) issue in Nest js
I am unable to display data from my API. I have attached images from my console and network tab. It worked fine when I was using localhost issue is in production. And the weird thing is all endpoints work from postman and some work in my frontend some don't. I said it's CORS issue since it sometimes log
'api endpoint/stock' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request
My main.js:
app.use(cors({
    origin: ["http://localhost:3000"],// I have tried * too

    methods: 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS',
    allowedHeaders: 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization',
    credentials: true,
  }));



I have tried
app.enableCors({ credentials: true, origin: "*" });

app.use(cors());



None of those errors show a problem with CORS, just bad (400) and unauthenticated (401) requests and

Also, all of the CORS preflight requests show a 204 (no content) response, not redirects.

I have added the one that has CORS error

Is the admin3.gereb.net/stock API anything to do with you? If not, you're going to have to proxy the requests to it through your backend to get around CORS.

Some end points work fine as u see on the first image like total and /sales the implementation of the guard is exactly the same some work fine some return 401 in production

Hmm, a 401 (Unauthorized) tends to indicate a request without authentication. If your account didn't have access to the specific api endpoints I would expect a 403 (Forbidden) response though. Can you confirm that the necessary credentials are actually being sent along with those requests.

Can you modify the question adding working API request headers and the 401 APi request

I fixed it, the issue was I was using @GET() then I changed it to @GET('all') it worked, a weird bug maybe but it works fine with localhost. Thanks for the help
